Fish needs a lazy evulation to remove an element from a list
I'm running Fish version 3.7.0, and I want to write a function to remove elements from lists, based on their index.
For instance, I want to remove the element from PATH environment variable at index 2:
set -l variable_name PATH
set -l index 2
set -e $variable_name[$index]

However, the follow statement does not work, it returns:

set: --erase: option requires an argument

I see it requires some lazy evaluation to get the variable name (e.g. PATH), but I didn't figure how to do that.

This should work: set -e {$variable_name}[$index] -- separate the indexing syntax from the expansion of the variable name.

@glennjackman Thank you! It works!!

The issue is that fish takes $var[$foo] as "the footh element of $var", where you want "expand $var, expand $foo, and attach both together".
You can use a variety of ways to express what you want, the cleanest is probably:
set -e $variable_name[1][$index]

This will expand the first element of $variable_name ("PATH"), the other [] will not be syntactically special, so it will end up running
set -e PATH[2]

like you want.
Alternatives include quoting (set -e "$variable_name"[$index]), brace expansions (set -e {$variable_name}[$index]) - you really just need to separate the $var from the [$foo] part. Even setting index to [2] and using set -e $variable_name$index works.
